# Query that counts Networkdays between Creation Date and Payment Date takes for ever to execute

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query when ran with the SELECT COUNT sub query runs instantaneous add in the COUNT and takes hours.

Row number less than 500,000

What I am aiming to achieve is count the number of days between the creation date and payment date excluding weekends and the hard coded public holidays.

This code works fine when I narrow it down to a single invoice in the where clause.

Tried a single invoice
 Tried removing the count clause both work but need/want the count in

```
Select APA.INVOICE_ID 
,         TO_CHAR(APA.INVOICE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') INVOICE_DATE
,         TO_CHAR(APA.CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') CREATION_DATE
,         TO_CHAR(APA.INVOICE_RECEIVED_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') RECEIVED_DATE
,         TO_CHAR(APA.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1,'DD/MM/YYYY') as Date_Rec_Branch
,         APA.INVOICE_NUM
,         TO_CHAR(APA.GL_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') GL_DATE
,         AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID
,         AIP.CHECK_ID

,         ACA.CHECK_NUMBER as PAYMENT_NUMBER
,         TO_CHAR(ACA.CHECK_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') PAYMENT_DATE
,         GLC.SEGMENT2
,         AID.ACCOUNTING_DATE
,         (SELECT COUNT(dat.dt)
      FROM   (SELECT APA.CREATION_DATE - 1 + rownum AS dt
              FROM all_objects
              WHERE APA.CREATION_DATE - 1 + rownum <= ACA.CHECK_DATE) dat
      WHERE TO_CHAR(dat.dt, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  NOT IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY') 
      AND TO_CHAR(dat.dt,'DD/MM/YYYY') NOT IN ( '01/01/2019', '25/12/2019', '26/12/2019', '26/08/2019', '19/04/2019', '22/04/2019', '06/05/2019', '27/05/2019'))as NWD_CREATION_PAYMENT

From AP_INVOICES_ALL APA
,        AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL AID
,        AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL AIP
,        AP_CHECKS_ALL ACA
,        GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLC

Where APA.INVOICE_ID = AID.INVOICE_ID
AND APA.INVOICE_ID = AIP.INVOICE_ID
AND AIP.CHECK_ID = ACA.CHECK_ID
AND AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID

AND AID.ACCOUNTING_DATE BETWEEN :Start_Date AND :End_Date

AND AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE = 'ITEM'
AND ACA.VOID_DATE is NULL
```

Faster Version

```
SELECT t1.invoice_date
,      t1.creation_date
,      t1.received_date
,      t1.date_rec_branch
,      t1.invoice_num
,      t1.gl_date
,      t1.dist_code_combination_id
,      t1.check_id
,      t1.payment_number
,      t1.payment_date
,      t1.segment2
,      t1.accounting_date
  --
,      (SELECT COUNT(dat.dt)
            FROM   (SELECT t1.start_date - 1 + rownum AS dt
                    FROM   all_objects
                    WHERE  t1.start_date - 1 + rownum <= t1.end_date) dat
            WHERE  TO_CHAR   (dat.dt, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')      NOT      IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY') 
    AND    TO_CHAR(dat.dt,'DD/MM/YYYY') NOT IN ( '01/01/2019', '25/12/2019', '26/12/2019', '26/08/2019', '19/04/2019', '22/04/2019', '06/05/2019', '27/05/2019')) as NWD_CREATION_PAYMENT
FROM   (
        Select APA.INVOICE_ID 
        ,      TO_CHAR(APA.INVOICE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') INVOICE_DATE
        ,      TO_CHAR(APA.CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') CREATION_DATE
        ,      TO_CHAR(APA.INVOICE_RECEIVED_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') RECEIVED_DATE
        ,      TO_CHAR(APA.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1,'DD/MM/YYYY') as Date_Rec_Branch
        ,      APA.INVOICE_NUM
        ,      TO_CHAR(APA.GL_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') GL_DATE
        ,      AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID
        ,      AIP.CHECK_ID
        ,      ACA.CHECK_NUMBER as PAYMENT_NUMBER
        ,      TO_CHAR(ACA.CHECK_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') PAYMENT_DATE
        ,      GLC.SEGMENT2
        ,      AID.ACCOUNTING_DATE
        ,      APA.CREATION_DATE    start_date
        ,      ACA.CHECK_DATE       end_date
         From AP_INVOICES_ALL APA
        ,        AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL AID
        ,        AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL AIP
        ,        AP_CHECKS_ALL ACA
        ,        GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLC
        Where APA.INVOICE_ID             = AID.INVOICE_ID
        AND APA.INVOICE_ID               = AIP.INVOICE_ID
        AND AIP.CHECK_ID                 = ACA.CHECK_ID
        AND AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID

        AND AID.ACCOUNTING_DATE BETWEEN  :Start_Date AND :End_Date

        AND AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE    = 'ITEM'
        AND ACA.VOID_DATE                is NULL
       ) t1
 WHERE 1=1
```

---

### JOINS SYNTAX CHANGED-Much Easier to Read

```
SELECT t1.invoice_date
,      t1.creation_date
,      t1.start_date2 as Invoice_Rec_Date
,      t1.date_rec_Branch
,      t1.invoice_num
,      t1.payment_number
,      t1.check_date
,      t1.segment2
,      t1.accounting_date
--
,      (SELECT COUNT(dat.dt)
        FROM   (SELECT t1.start_date2 - 1 + rownum AS dt
                FROM   all_objects
                WHERE  t1.start_date2 - 1 + rownum <= t1.end_date) dat
        WHERE  TO_CHAR(dat.dt, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  NOT IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY') 
        AND    TO_CHAR(dat.dt,'DD/MM/YYYY') NOT IN ( '01/01/2019', '25/12/2019', '26/12/2019', '26/08/2019', '19/04/2019', '22/04/2019', '06/05/2019', '27/05/2019')) as NWD_REC_PAYMENT
,      (SELECT COUNT(dat.dt)
        FROM   (SELECT t1.start_date - 1 + rownum AS dt
                FROM   all_objects
                WHERE  t1.start_date - 1 + rownum <= t1.end_date) dat
        WHERE  TO_CHAR(dat.dt, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  NOT IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY') 
        AND    TO_CHAR(dat.dt,'DD/MM/YYYY') NOT IN ( '01/01/2019', '25/12/2019', '26/12/2019', '26/08/2019', '19/04/2019', '22/04/2019', '06/05/2019', '27/05/2019')) as NWD_CREATION_PAYMENT

FROM   ( SELECT APA.INVOICE_DATE
        ,      APA.CREATION_DATE
        ,      APA.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1 as Date_Rec_Branch
        ,      APA.INVOICE_NUM


        ,      ACA.CHECK_NUMBER as PAYMENT_NUMBER
        ,      ACA.CHECK_DATE
        ,      AID.ACCOUNTING_DATE
        ,      APA.INVOICE_RECEIVED_DATE     start_date2
        ,      APA.CREATION_DATE    start_date
        ,      ACA.CHECK_DATE       end_date
        ,      GLC.SEGMENT2

        FROM AP_INVOICES_ALL APA

        JOIN   AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL AID
        ON     APA.INVOICE_ID = AID.INVOICE_ID

        JOIN   AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL AIP
        ON     APA.INVOICE_ID = AIP.INVOICE_ID

        JOIN   AP_CHECKS_ALL ACA
        ON     AIP.CHECK_ID = ACA.CHECK_ID

        JOIN   GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GLC
        ON     AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID


        WHERE APA.INVOICE_NUM NOT LIKE 'EXP-%'
        AND   AID.ACCOUNTING_DATE BETWEEN  :Start_Date AND :End_Date
        AND   AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE    = 'ITEM'
        AND   APA.INVOICE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN ('CREDIT' , 'PREPAYMENT')
        AND   ACA.VOID_DATE is NULL ) t1


WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
    and [QUERY PLAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: This type of joining is more complicated to me I prefer if I need left or rights etc to use the (+) however I am very new to SQL

Comment: I have changed this code now and it runs much faster.

Comment: Again that kind of writing JOINS was declared obsolete for a reason. You can check the link for more details.

Comment: isn't the (+) the latest way of doing joins in Oracle SQL/BI Publisher

Comment: You aren't using (+) either

Comment: No because I want an equal join not a right or left eg only show records from both tables where  they match

Comment: @Leighholling: even Oracle recommends to stop using the proprietary `(+)` outer join operator and use an explicit `left join` instead.

Comment: Thanks I will start getting into this habbit what if I don't want a left or right join?

Comment: use INNER JOIN or just JOIN

Comment: Just read that article and I like it I understand the syntax of it better now and why. I just need to understand join types better now

Answer (score 0):

put the results of NWD_CREATION_PAYMENT in a temp table first and add it as an inner join in the main query.

Comment: How would I do this by the use of from Dual?

Comment: Any have an example of putting my NWD_CREATION_PAYMENT into a temp table?